# Javascript: Adding fields dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have a html page which looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script language="javascript">
    fields = 0;
    function addInput() {
       if ( fields != 3) {
          document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<input type='text'         name='clients_form[clients_name]' size='32' maxlength='32' value='' id='clients_form_clients_name' />";
          fields += 1;'
       } else {
          document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<br />More then 3 not allowed.";
          document.form.add.disabled = true;
       }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
    <input type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add More" />
</form>
<div id="text">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly fine for me. It adds text fields when the button is clicked. 
But, I have another select tag which needs to be added dynamically when the button is clicked as well. The select form is as below:

```
<select id="client_category_name" name="client_category[name]">
   <option value="">Select Category</option>
   <option value="1">internal</option>
   <option value="2">external</option>
   <option value="3">others</option>
</select>
```

**How do we add this select tag alongside the input tag.** I am a ruby on rails developer and finding it hard to implement it.

Comment: why don't you use jQuery ? it will be much easier.

Comment: Sure, but how do we write the same function using jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script >
fields = 0;
function addInput() {
if (fields != 3) {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<input type='text' name='clients_form[clients_name]' size='32' maxlength='32' value='' id='clients_form_clients_name_"+fields+"' />"+
'<select id="client_category_name_'+fields+'" name="client_category[]"><option value="">Select Category</option><option value="1">internal</option><option value="2">external</option><option value="3">others</option></select>';
fields = fields+ 1;
} else {
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<br />More then 3 not allowed.";
document.form.add.disabled=true;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
<input type="button" onclick="addInput();" name="add" value="Add More" />
</form>
<div id="text">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Is it possible to dynamically change the id of both the fields when a user adds more. So at first:
id = "client_category_name_1" second: id = "client_category_name_2" and at last id = "client_category_name_3" as we are not going to add more then 3. Id should change for both input and select tag?

Comment: yes. i've edited the code to chage the id aswell.Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Ok assuming you already have [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) library

```
$("#text").append("<input type='text' name='clients_form[clients_name]' size='32' maxlength='32' value='' id='clients_form_clients_name' />");
```

same goes on the `select` and for readable code. you can put it first on a variable

```
var mySelect ="";
mySelect += '<select id="client_category_name" name="client_category[name]">';
mySelect += '<option value="">Select Category</option>';
```

etc....

```
$("#text").append(mySelect);
```